# Captive Portal esp8266

Tags: html, c++, ajax, esp8266

Нужна помощь с проэктом на esp8266. Пытаюсь сделать что то вроде чата. Совместил несколько примеров и написал html страничку. По идее оно должно принимать ввод пользователя на страничке в Captive Portal. Но это не работает, данные просто не отправляются. Хотя в обычном браузере по этому ip всё работает. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема?

Код:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

const byte DNS_PORT = 53;
IPAddress apIP(172, 0, 0, 1);
DNSServer dnsServer;
ESP8266WebServer webServer(80);

String handleRoot = ""
"<!DOCTYPE html>"
"<html lang='en'>"
   "<head>"
     "<meta charset='utf-8'>"
     "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>"
   "</head>"
    "<body>"
      "<h1>Ввод:</h1>"
      "<input type='text' name='date_hh' id='date_hh' size=2 autofocus>" 
      "<div>"
      "<br><button id='save_button'>Save</button>"
      "</div>"
    "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>"   
    "<script>"
      "var hh;"
      "$('#save_button').click(function(e){"
        "e.preventDefault();"
         "hh = $('#date_hh').val();"   
         "$.get('/save?hh=' + hh, function(data){"
          "console.log(data);"
        "});"
      "});"    
    "</script>"
  "</body>"
"</html>";




void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println("Started");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));
  WiFi.softAP("INFO");


  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);

  webServer.onNotFound([]() {
  webServer.send(200, "text/html", handleRoot);
  });
  webServer.begin();
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(webServer.arg("hh"));
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  webServer.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, что такое Captive Portal, и что значит, что в браузере все работает. Я правильно понимаю, что Вы загружаете скомпилированный код в устройство, запускаете его, и в браузере открывается нужная вам страница? или нет?

Comment: Captive Portal, это: сетевой сервис, требующий от подключившегося к Сети пользователя выполнить некоторые действия для получения доступа в Интернет. Да, я загружаю код в это устройство, далее оно создаёт точку доступа к которой подключаюсь я. Сразу же после подключения меня перенаправляет в Captive Portal, в нём есть я так понимаю свой браузер в котором и открывается весь html и js код. Так вот, в обычном браузере оно работает, а в браузере Сaptive portal нет. Скорее всего это происходит потому что "внутренний" браузер не поддерживает локальное сохранение. Наверное нужно использовать cookie.

Comment: Да, в обычном браузере всё работает отлично. Проблема скорее всего в Ajax. Почему я хочу это сделать на Captive Portal? Потому что так удобнее, я могу подключиться к вай фай, и оно само перебросит на страничку. А если без этого, то нужно еще заходить в браузер и вводить IP.

Comment: Я думаю, Вы очень хорошо продвинулись в этой задаче. Но, мне кажется, есть одно неясное место: 1) вот Вы запустили код, есп созадала вайфай вокруг себя, когда Вы подключились к нему, Вы можете войти на 172.0.0.1. 2) А теперь предположим, что Вы вошли в Captive Portal. Как я понимаю - это публичный сайт. Как пакеты с captive portal попадут на устройство?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Но мне это и не нужно. Этот код для эксперимента, что вводимые данные передаются на саму плату. В будущем я напишу что бы они просто загружались в её память и в конечном итоге выводились на страничке. (Сразу не понял, устройство это esp, или же телефон?)

Comment: Если вопрос заключается в том как данные из браузера попадают на плату, то просто java script читает эти данные, далее сохраняет их в переменную, а затем эта переменная передаётся в с++(по идее оно так работает).

Comment: Не совсем так. Мне показалось, что есп-шка у вас вообще не подключена к интернету. Я рассуждал так: если она образует свой совственный вайфай, то, вполне возможно, у Вас при подключении к этому вайфаю есть локальная беспроводная сеть, котрая не подключена к интернету. Но потом я посмотрел и увидел, что аджакс загружается из cdn. И тут я перестал понимать, как работает сеть. Мой вопрос - как устройчтво подключено к интернету?

Comment: Спасибо! Мне кажется это ответ) Я даже как то не обратил на это внимание... У меня есть тогда встречный вопрос, есть ли способ как при добавлении нового содержимого на страницу из памяти этой платы, не перезагружать её? Всё это без подключения к интернету. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: А, возможно, у Вас аджакс закеширован в браузере. Это бы многое объяснило, хотя, ВОЗМОЖНО у вас в случае отсутствия соединения с интенетом не работал бы DNS - все ссылки не открывались бы.

Comment: Оно  по моей идее должно быть автономным от интернета. Что бы его можно было включить в любом месте и зайти на эту страничку например или т.д.

Comment: > Оно ... должно быть автономным от интернета - а я правильно понимаю, что тогда чатится смогут только те, кто физически подключился к этой же вайфай сети?

Comment: Или же лучше сделать как нормальные люди это всё что бы esp подключилась к роутеру с интернетом. А потом пользователь который подключён к этому wi fi(от роутера), может по локальному ip подключиться к этой плате.

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете.

Comment: > сделать ... это всё с подключением к роутеру с интернетом - это решило бы некоторые  проблемы, например, с доступом к ajax. При этом у Вас роутер будет выдавать еспшке- как клиенту - некотрый другой ip, чем 172.0.0.1. И на этот - другой - ip надо будет и вешать сервер, и заходить браузером. Так что есть и недостатки

Comment: Да, так я завтра и попробую сделать. К тому же, если правильно  всё сделать к ней будет доступ из всего мира) Спасибо Вам за консультацию!

Comment: ю а велкам, как говорится. Но наверняка будут еще трудности, например, придётся "пробрасывать порт" через роутер

Comment: Я с этим уже знаком) Недавно учил socket на python. Задача была соединить два пк не в локальной сети через tcp. Так я тогда очень много чего пробовал просидел так дня 3, включая и перенаправление портов. А моя ошибка была в том что я использовал мой ip адрес из сайта 2ip(да и вообще из онлайн сервисов). А потом как то случайно в настройках роутера увидел совсем другой ip, попробовал его и всё получилось.

Comment: > У меня есть тогда встречный вопрос, есть ли способ как при добавлении нового содержимого на страницу из памяти этой платы, не перезагружать её? - только заметил этот вопрос. Как я себе представляю, можно модифицировать DOM из JS. Наверное, это вопрос стоит задать отдельно. И -да, все современные html- чаты работают без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Ясно, тогда уже сегодня днём буду искать информацию об этом.

Comment: ну,  Вас такой серьезный проект получается. Грубо говоря, чтобы сделать чат, надо написать обработку сообщений на WEB-сервере. Веб сервер у вас на esp-шке. получается, что он должен принимать новые сообщения от любого из участников чата и отдавать их всем остальным участникам чата. я бы сделал это через REST- но есть ли rest в этой малютке, есп-шке? второй варинат - это веб-сокет, опять таки, надо смотреть поддержку его на esp. я бы начал с rest.

Comment: Я прочитал про этот rest api, хорошая штука. Нужно будет разобраться в ней. Спасибо за информацию!

Comment: кстати, я прикинул, если веб-сервер на с++ - то рест сервер реализовать не очень сложно, даже если его поддержкт еще нет в веб сервере для esp. Я бы прочитал пример https://habr.com/ru/post/252519/

Comment: Спасибо, попробую интегрировать этот пример в код для esp. А затем его переписать.